# Firebase hosting : SSL Certificate has expired and haven't been renewed

Tags: ssl, firebase, lets-encrypt, firebase-hosting

Tonight our website https://guestme.live went down because an SSL issue. On my browser Chrome I get this error : NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID.

Looking for the certificate provided by firebase hosting (from letsencrypt), the expiration date is 13 feb. 2017. Don't know why it hasn't be renewed and how to resolve this issue. I try to contact firebase support...

Validity
Not Before: Nov 15 22:08:00 2016 GMT
Not After : Feb 13 22:08:00 2017 GMT

Comment: See answer below. In general when you see this sort of problem, it's best to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Hello @frank. Sure but you answer and give explanation, not the support. The situation was critical, our website was down, we needed more explanations than the answer we get by email.. Your answer was more clear, and faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

This is a known problem that started at 3PM PST today with some certificates on Firebase hosting. The root cause has since been fixed.

Keep an eye on the [status page for the issue](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Hosting/17001) for updates, including instructions on how to fix the issue if you're still affected.

Comment: Hi Frank, are you sure this is completely resolved? I saw this on an iOS Safari this morning. Certificate issued by GlobalSign and expired on 2/12/17 11:40:15  I just posted a message on the Firebase Google Groups as well

Comment: Seems like they didn't fix their issues, as it's now mid-february 2018, and my certs are expired too.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you're having problems. Unfortunately certificate expiration is a necessity to create a more secure web. But it is **extremely** doubtful though that your expired certificate is caused by the same certificate expiration problems from a year ago though. If you're having similar problems, your best bet is to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. Alternatively: post a new question with enough details for others to troubleshoot.