# Do SSL Certificates in Firebase Hosting expire?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Do Firebase’s free SSL certificates on your custom domain expire? If so, how do I renew it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase Hosting certificates (like all SSL certificates) may expire, but will in that case be auto-renewed.

If there is a problem on your domain due to certificate expiration, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. There is nothing more **you** can do about it.

Comment: This is the first time "There is nothing more you can do about it" is a positive statement, Firebase is great!

Answer (score 1):

Try to read the Official Google Documentation regarding Firebase

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

Also, check this stackOverflow ticket, it also discussed about expiration

- [Firebase hosting : SSL Certificate has expired and haven't been renewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215869/firebase-hosting-ssl-certificate-has-expired-and-havent-been-renewed)